# force_load linker flag for other platforms

Tags: linker, ld

I need to include all symbols from a static library. "-force_load" is good when compiling with Xcode. But, for example, when using it  under Ubuntu with gcc, "-force_load" is not recognized. I'm looking for alternative options that can be used under other operating systems. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU linker's option is called `--whole-archive`, but while `-force_load` applies to one library, `--whole-archive` applies to all libraries after it on the command line. So the usual thing is to do `--whole-archive somelib.a --no-whole-archive`.

Usually you don't use ld directly but instead invoke it via GCC, in which case you have to tell GCC to pass the options on to the linker: `-Wl,--whole-archive,somelib.a,--no-whole-archive`